# Tidy up if statement - can an object not instantiated be in an AND operator

Tags: c#, if-statement

Can I put an object.property which hasn't been instantiated on the right hand side of an 'AND' operator if I know that the left hand side will fail but if the left side passes the right side will be instantiated?

In the example below the first if/else statement sets up the other if statement for the above question. Although I've tested that it doesn't show errors, I was wondering what happens behind the scenes or is there a better way.(there are many if/else statements that use the results of the first if/else statement.

```
        if (_articleGuid.Equals(Guid.Empty))
        {
            isArticleGuid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            article = new Article(Guid.Empty, _articleGuid);
            bodyText = article.Text;
            articleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(article.DateActive);

            isArticleGuid = true;
        }

        if(isArticleGuid && article.Author != null)
        {
            divAuthor.InnerText = article.Author;                        
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, this is safe. The `article` variable will need to be definitely assigned, but the language guarantees that if the LHS expression of an `&&` operator evaluates to false, the RHS expression won't be evaluated - so you're not going to get a `NullReferenceException`.

From the C# 3.0 language specification, section 7.11:

> The operation `x && y` corresponds to the operation `x & y`, except that `y` is evaluated only if `x` is not false.

Comment: Thats correct I don't get any errors and hoped it wasn't bad coding practise to do it this way otherwise its extra if statements eg if(isArticleGuid)....if(article.Author != null)

Comment: No, it's absolutely fine to rely on this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is fine because the `&&` operator is guaranteed to be short-circuiting.

To be more safe you could check that article is not null instead of / as well as checking isArticleGuid.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, the logical and operator `&&` evaluates its arguments from left to right and uses short circuit evaluation. That means that if the first argument evaluates to `false` then the second will never be evaluated.

Using this isn't bad coding practice - it's an well known idiom common to many languages with C style syntax (C, C++, C#, D, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a aside, and further to Jon's answer, VB .Net can also do short-circuit evaluation with the new (and ugly, IMO) 'AndAlso' and 'OrElse' keywords.

```
If SomeRef IsNot Null AndAlso SomeRef.Property = 42 Then
...etc
```